# How do I play videos in a pop up

Tags: magento2.3, popup, video

I'd like to be able to show a video thumbnail, and when you click on it, the video plays in a pop up. What is the best/easiest way to implement that? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Look into venobox

I built a page using it that does what you are asking

https://veno.es/venobox/